# spectre_v2=retpoline and performance

Tags: kernel-parameters

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089426/what-is-a-retpoline-and-how-does-it-work

> https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html?highlight=kernel%20parameters
>
> *Control mitigation of Spectre variant 2 (indirect branch speculation) vulnerability;
> the default operation protects the kernel from user space attacks.*
>
> ```
>                   spectre_v2=
>
>                    on   - unconditionally enable, implies
>                           spectre_v2_user=on
>                    off  - unconditionally disable, implies
>                           spectre_v2_user=off
>                    auto - kernel detects whether your CPU model is
>                           vulnerable
>
>                    Selecting 'on' will, and 'auto' may, choose a
>                    mitigation method at run time according to the
>                    CPU, the available microcode, the setting of the
>                    CONFIG_RETPOLINE configuration option, and the
>                    compiler with which the kernel was built.
>
>                    Selecting 'on' will also enable the mitigation
>                    against user space to user space task attacks.
>
>                    Selecting 'off' will disable both the kernel and
>                    the user space protections.
>
>                    Specific mitigations can also be selected manually:
>
>                    retpoline         - replace indirect branches
>                    retpoline,generic - google's original retpoline
>                    retpoline,amd     - AMD-specific minimal thunk
>
>                    Not specifying this option is equivalent to
>                    spectre_v2=auto.
> ```

For best computing performance such as in hpc and a controlled environment where I know no user is (a) able to do this exploit (they have enough trouble logging in) and (b) would gain nothing anyway if they were able to perform such a feat, should i be setting this kernel parameter to off?  This would be on a server having an Intel LGA 3647 platinum 8xxx series cpu and when installing RHEL 7.9 it automatically did `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX= sceptre_v2=retpoline`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you're confident in your border controls and are willing to accept the risk vs. performance impact, you can certainly set `spectre_v2=off` to not enable any Spectre/Meltdown mitigations. To ensure their unmitigated-ness, you can use this quick-n-dirty script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Works in RHEL7; does not work in RHEL8

items="pti_enabled retp_enabled ibrs_enabled"
DIR=/sys/kernel/debug/x86

echo "These should all be 0:"

for item in $items; do
        printf "%-13s " $item: ; cat $DIR/$item;
done
need_to_set=false
for item in $items; do
        grep -q 0 $DIR/$item || { echo "$item is not 0"; need_to_set=true; }
done
$need_to_set && {
        read -p "Found value(s) that are not 0. Enter 'y' if you want 0 them: " a
        [ "$a" = "y" ] && {
                for item in $items; do
                        echo 0 > $DIR/$item
                done
                echo Done.
                exit 0
        }
        echo "OK, will not set it to 0."
}
```

...of course, that will only disable the mitigations until a reboot. Modifying the kernel command line, as you suggest, is the way to make it stick.

This is as of RHEL 7.9, btw. I believe the command line option is the same in 8 but the check is different somehow.